# How can I disable the document listing in the File menu, after my menu items?

Tags: menu, mfc, mdi, menubar

I'm doing maintenance on a MFC MDI application and I need to remove child document window entries from the main window menu.
My File menu template has just an item, the Exit entry, but on execution the child windows get entries added there.

I'm not a MFC developer, and just hacking my way through it to change this bit. Maybe I understood things backwards... Please, illuminate me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the InitInstance function you can call LoadStdProfileSettings with 0 for the nMaxMRU parameter.

Comment: I guess I wasn't getting any relevant search results because I missed the MRU keyword. Thanks.

Comment: I did that and nothing changed. Maybe I'm setting this up somewhere else?

Comment: Scott, that didn't work. I can't find any other references in my code to the LoadStdProfileSettings, I'm stepping through the call and even so the documents window entries are placed in my File menu.